# Java Multithreading Application freezed

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, copy

If I start a second thread, for example to copy a file, why does my application freeze until that thread is finished? I thought that starting a second thread would be the solution for this problem.

Main code:

```
CopyFile Copy = new CopyFile();
Copy.start();
Copy.CopyFile("input.txt", "output.txt");
```

CopyFile.class

```
    public class CopyFile extends Thread 
    {
    public void CopyFile(File Input, File Output)
        {
            System.out.println("Copy file:" + Input.toString());
            System.out.println("Destination:" + Output.toString());

            InputStream InputReader = null;
            OutputStream OutputWriter = null;
            try 
            {
                InputReader = new FileInputStream(Input);
                OutputWriter = new FileOutputStream(Output);
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                int length;
                while ((length = InputReader.read(buffer)) > 0) 
                {
                    OutputWriter.write(buffer, 0, length);
                }
                InputReader.close();
                OutputWriter.close();
            }
            catch(FileNotFoundException e)
            {
                System.out.println("FileNotFoundException niggur");
            }
            catch(IOException e)
            {
                System.out.println("IOException niggur");
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: How was the first thread started? on which file? what time? does second thread try to read the same file?

Comment: You forgot to add a `catch(RacialSlurException e)` block ...  ;)  In all seriousness, we can't help you without seeing exactly how your threads are spawned and all the code between that point and your `CopyFile` method getting called.

Comment: Note that in java the coding conventions are generally to start method names with lowercase letters, and the same applies to method parameters too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### A bit of background...

Firstly, a bit of a best-practice thing... don't extend `Thread` implement `Runnable` instead. In fact, if you take a look at the JVM `Thread` class, you'll see that it implements `Runnable`.

When dealing with multiple threads, you need to place the code that you want to run on a separate thread inside the `Runnable`'s `void run()` method.

In your case, you start the thread, which has a default empty `void run()` method - so the second thread does nothing, then terminates.

Subsequently, on you call the `CopyFile` method. This is then run on your main thread, hence it blocking until it finished.

---

### How can you fix your example?

A) Change your class to implement `Runnable`, it should no longer extend `Thread`

B) Put your parameters for input / output files on the constructor of your class

C) To run your `Runnable` on a separate thread, pass it to a thread in the constructor

```
Thread thread = new Thread(new CopyFile("A.txt", "B.txt");
thread.start();
```

The resulting class should look something like this:

```
public static class CopyFile implements Runnable {
    private File input;
    private File output;

    public CopyFile(File input, File output) {
        this.input = input;
        this.output = output;
    }

    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Copy file:" + input.toString());
        System.out.println("Destination:" + output.toString());

        InputStream InputReader = null;
        OutputStream OutputWriter = null;
        try {
            InputReader = new FileInputStream(input);
            OutputWriter = new FileOutputStream(output);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int length;
            while ((length = InputReader.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                OutputWriter.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }
            InputReader.close();
            OutputWriter.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("FileNotFoundException");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("IOException");
        }
    }
}
```

---

### Further reading?

Creating a new thread every time you want to do a bit of work in parellel is bad practise, as it's quite a lot of work for the operating system to construct / destroy threads.

Instead, threads should be created up-front and they should subscribe to queues of work.

Google the "producer/consumer" pattern and work through a tutorial.

If this is a one-off action for you application it may not be worth using the producer/consumer pattern across an ExecutorService, but you should read up on these topics if you're considering widely using multi-threading in your application.

Comment: How can I 'send' the parameters to the thread? (The information to copy)

Comment: @MathijsAlexander Put them in the constructor of your CopyFile object. Otherwise take a look at producer/consumer, where you can pass round parameter objects with the details in.

Answer (score 0):

This has a basic problem. When you extend the `Thread` class, make sure you put your logic invocation inside the `public void run()` method. When the invoke the `start()` method of that, it will invoke the `run()` method eventually. This `run()` method is inherited from `Runnable` interface.

```
CopyFile copy = new CopyFile(in, out);
copy.start();
```

where;

```
public class CopyFile extends Thread 
{

    private File input;
    private File output;

    public CopyFile(File Input, File Output) {
        this.input = input;
        this.output = output;
    } 

    public void run() {
        copy();
    }

    public void copy()
    {
        System.out.println("Copy file:" + input.toString());
        System.out.println("Destination:" + output.toString());

        // rest of the code as it is...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for your program to be run in another thread you have to override the `run` method, whose signature is `public void run()` put your code in there it will be run in a separate thread.

Answer (score 0):

You Need to override the method `run` of the class Thread and call your method copyFile from the method `run`

Main code

```
CopyFile copy = new CopyFile(in, out);
copy.start();
```

Class CopyFile

```
public class CopyFile extends Thread {
File in, out;
public CopyFile(File in, File out) {
  this.in = in;
  this.out = out;
}
public void run() {
  copyFile(in, out);
}
public void copyFile(File Input, File Output)
    {
        System.out.println("Copy file:" + Input.toString());
        System.out.println("Destination:" + Output.toString());

        InputStream InputReader = null;
        OutputStream OutputWriter = null;
        try 
        {
            InputReader = new FileInputStream(Input);
            OutputWriter = new FileOutputStream(Output);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int length;
            while ((length = InputReader.read(buffer)) > 0) 
            {
                OutputWriter.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }
            InputReader.close();
            OutputWriter.close();
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            System.out.println("FileNotFoundException niggur");
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            System.out.println("IOException niggur");
        }
    }
}
```